# How to get note in hz from one-shot audio sample using Python?

Tags: python, audio, librosa

I need to get a note or tone of audio using python. I know about librosa.estimate_tuning, but I don't know how to convert it into hz. And maybe someone could say me another possible solution to my problem.

Comment: You're trying to get the most dominant pitch at any given time?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using 'aubio / pitch_tracking'. It has a python interface, and pitch tracking can be done in several unit including freqency(hz) or note (midi).

may be you can find some example here: 
https://github.com/aubio/aubio/tree/master/python/demos

```
pip install aubio

aubio  pitch   /myfile/Audio_6.wav 

0.000000    474.987762
0.005805    450.682312
0.011610    445.780945
0.017415    443.593994
0.023220    442.287903
0.029025    441.431763
0.034830    440.940826
0.040635    440.775452
0.046440    440.760834
0.052245    440.760803
0.058050    440.760773
0.063855    440.760742
0.069660    440.760773
0.075465    440.760773
0.081270    440.760803
0.087075    440.760803
0.092880    440.760803
0.098685    440.760773
0.104490    440.760773
0.110295    440.760834
0.116100    440.760803
0.121905    440.760773
0.127710    440.760773
0.133515    440.760742
0.139320    440.760834
```

as you can see its judging my input audio wav file to be 440 Hz which is spot on